# Determining the subfield of rational function field with a given subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $n$ to be a positive integer. Let $L$ to be the rational function field $\mathbb{C}(X_1,...,X_n)$ of $n$ variables over $\mathbb{C}$, and $S\subset L$ to be a given finite subset of $L$.
Consider the subfield  $$K=\{f\in L: \forall x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n, \text{if}\; \forall P\in S, P(x)=P(y), \text{then}\; f(x)=f(y)\}$$ of $L$.
Then my question is that is $K$ just the subfield of $L$ generated by elements of the given subset $S$? If not, what should $K$ to be? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does $P(x)$ mean for a rational function $P$ and an arbitrary point $x$?

Comment: @ Mohan Forgive me for my naive opinion. $P(X)$ can be written as a quotient of two polynmials, say $P(X)=\frac{P_1(X)}{P_2(X)}$, and we can assume $\mathbf{gcd}(P_1,P_2)=1$. Then for all point $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $P_2(x)\neq 0$,  the value of $P$ at the point $x$ is a complex number. If  $x$ is a zero point of  $P_2$, then define $P(x)$ to be $\infty$, which is not a complex number anymore.

Comment: This is not a good option. It is possible that both $P_i(x)$ could be zero and then you get zero divided by zero. As an example, with $n=2$, what is the value of $X_1/X_2$ at the origin?